# Can I wire a receptacle to a cord and plug?

Tags: wiring, code-compliance, home-theater, surge-suppression

I am planning to add a recessed wall box for my TV so I can put the connections behind its wall mount. Most of these boxes come with a pass-through of some sort as well as a spot for a single-gang receptacle.

I'd like to put a 20A (NEMA 5-20R) receptacle here, so I don't need to run the power cable very far, but I'd also like for it to be surge protected.

I know I can get surge-protected receptacles, but given the consumable nature of a surge protector, I'd rather wire the receptacle to a cord-and-plug termination (a NEMA 5-20P) and plug it into my existing surge protector.

I'm having trouble finding if there is a code-compliant (NEC 2014 or 2017, which my jurisdiction will soon adopt) way to do this.

My current thought is to wire this receptacle *only* to another receptacle so they form an isolated circuit. Then, I get a cord, doubly-terminated with NEMA 5-20P ends and I plug one end into the "other" receptacle and the other end into the surge protector.

Comment: Not sure I completely follow, but it sounds like you want to make a male-male cable, which is definitely not safe for 120v.

Comment: What's the point of the intermediate receptacle? Code aside, why not just connect the male end of an extension cord to the recessed receptacle and plug that into your surge protector?

Comment: you can get a wall mount *inlet* made for  just this purpose.

Comment: @cactuscake (and Tom, but I can only tag one person). It's only dangerous if you unplug the wrong side first, but yeah, that's true...

Comment: @isherwood Just so I don't need to snake an extension cord behind the wall, and I need both outlets on the receptacle, so I can't take one up to power it. Assuming I understand what you're saying...

Comment: @agentp What are these called? Do they have a specific name?

Comment: When I get a moment, I'll upload a more complete picture. This started out simple and quickly got complicated.

Comment: if you look for kits made for wall mounting tv's you should find them. Its just called an "inlet" as far as I can tell (recessed port with male prongs to which you plug the female end of an extension cord.)

Comment: @agentp Almost all I'd seen so far have regularly wired receptacles (ex. side wire). I'll look again for ones terminated with a plug.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00193QP92/ref=asc_df_B00193QP925384828/?tag=hyprod-20&creative=394997&creativeASIN=B00193QP92&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198062682203&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4582751208327435992&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9015764&hvtargid=pla-319935013565

Comment: @agentp Ah, I see. I think I misunderstood you. I thought there was a receptacle that came with an extension cord sticking out the back. This is basically what I described, but without the suicide cord, right?

Comment: I've done a lot of insane things with mains power.  I have **never** had **any reason** to fabricate a suicide cable.  Anyone who thinks a suicide cable is any kind of option *doesn't know enough Code to realize how many other creative options are entirely legal*.

Comment: @Harper I've seen inlets before (like on the side of food trucks for "shore power"), but completely forgot about them for this purpose. The good news is that there is still no reason to use a suicide cable.

Comment: @HariGanti inlets are one of the reasons I don't need suicide cables.  In this question I feel like you are XYing us.  This is a super dorky way to do this.  What you *actually* want is surge protection on the branch circuit going to the TV, yes?  You just want to use a power strip for the surge suppression and think the suppression must be inline with the load, yes?  Have you actually done a teardown on one and is that true? (Betting not).  Let me ask you this. **Is there an accessible junction box in any unimproved space on the circuit *before* the TV?**. I want to put something there.

Comment: @Harper I have no idea what XYing is... As for your question, I don't know if surge protection needs to be inline with the load, but I've never heard evidence for a surge protector in parallel protecting anything either. With a MOV or a TVS, it seems it would have to be inline, however. As I stated in my post, I want to use a cord-and-plug surge protector because they are consumables and I don't want to replace a hardwired receptacle or surge suppressor. Otherwise, I'd just use a surge-protecting receptacle and there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ......... [Surge suppressor teardowns](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=power+strip+teardown+video&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) prepare to be surprised and disappointed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73758/discussion-between-hari-ganti-and-harper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use an inlet (or a full in-wall TV power kit, if required by the AHJ)

What you want for getting power back into the wall isn't a second outlet, but its mirror image, namely an *inlet* (product shown for exposition only):

[image: flanged 5-15 inlet]

That way, you can use a (short) length of ordinary extension cord between the surge protector and the inlet, then have normal building wiring from the inlet to another outlet.  This is similar to a 400.7 (11) setup:

> (11) Between an existing receptacle outlet and an inlet, where the inlet provides power to an additional single receptacle outlet.  The wiring interconnecting the inlet to the single receptacle outlet shall be a Chapter 3 wiring method.  The inlet, receptacle outlet, and Chapter 3 wiring method, including the flexible cord and fittings, shall be a listed assembly specific for this application.

only with the surge suppressor in the middle, which to me, would make it fall under 400.7 point 6 instead (you're facilitating the interchange of the surge suppressor or other intermediate device here).  However, your AHJ may require a 400.7 (11) kit -- these are called "in-wall TV power kits" generically, but are sometimes known by a trade name of "PowerBridge".  These include the inlet, outlet, and the wiring between them in the wall, and typically are designed to be easily field fitted, using an integral connector system.

Comment: Thanks for providing a code reference. Article 400.7(11) is interesting because I was specifically planning to use one that didn't have an inlet as part of the kit.

Comment: I'm going to post another question soon, but to clarify article 400.7, you can't run an appliance's cord through a wall, correct? That seems to be specifically prohibited unless it qualifies as "[facilitating] frequent interchange"

Comment: @HariGanti -- you can't run the cord through the wall, but a 400.7(11) kit makes it so that you don't have to :)

Comment: That's what I thought... I also want to mount a soundbar, but that's only 2" tall, so it'd be nearly impossible to conceal the plug with a conventional kit. That and the kits are insanely overpriced.

Comment: @HariGanti not even then.  Cords through walls are nope, unless they're doorbell, thermostat, phone, ethernet and jazz like that... speaker...

Comment: @Harper Thanks for the clarification. Essentially, I need to find a <2" receptacle wall plate.

Comment: The one I found for this purpose is 2.5" tall: https://www.powerbridgesolution.com/product/soundbar-solution